# reset button that won't reset properly in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I've created 3 buttons, when you push one of them, indicates how many times you have clicked on that button.

I succeeded in making the button work properly.
But the reset button I made is broken, which is the issue.

when you click the rest button it's going to '0' but after starting the button press again counting starts from '2' or '3', not from the number '1'.

please help me to sort this matter.

```js
let btns=document.querySelectorAll('.box');
let reset=document.getElementById('rest');


    btns.forEach(btn => {   
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                btn.innerText= ++ btn.value;
        });
});


reset.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        btns.forEach(btn => {
                btn.innerText= 0;
        });     
       
});
```

```css
button{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button class="box" value="0">0</button>
    <button class="box" value="0">0</button>
    <button class="box" value="0">0</button>

    <button id="rest">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

get the `innerText` and then add 1 to it per click.

1. You're getting the value of the button, but are never setting it
2. You're not parsing the value as an int. You can't use ++ or calculating functions on strings, but getting a value or text from an element always returns a string type, not an integer.

```js
let btns=document.querySelectorAll('.box');
let reset=document.getElementById('rest');


    btns.forEach(btn => {   
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                btn.innerText= parseInt(btn.innerText) + 1;
        });
});


reset.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        btns.forEach(btn => {
                btn.innerText= 0;
        });     
       
});
```

Thanks to NoobishPro

Comment: Was writing an answer but you were ahead of me. However, I'd still like to add a small explanation, as is preferred on stack, so I'll do it as a comment as this answer should  be the fix already.


1 ) You're getting the value of the button, but are never setting it
2 ) You're not parsing the value as an int. You can't use ++ or calculating functions on strings, but getting a value or text from an element always returns a string type, not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the btn text to 0 when reset. You also have to set the button value to 0. Which you are incrementing. As result when you reset only text is changed, value reamains the same.

```
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
let reset = document.getElementById('rest')

btns.forEach(btn => {   
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    btn.innerText = parseInt(btn.innerText) + 1
  })
})


reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.innerText = 0
    btn.value = 0
  })
})
```